# What is the word/noun that describes the concept of a process being 32-bit vs 64-bit?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm struggling to come up with the proper word to describe this concept. Like if I want to talk about whether a process is a 32-bit process or a 64-bit process, I want to talk about its ______?

"Bitness?" I don't know. "Bit size?"

Sorry if this isn't the correct StackExchange site for this, I wasn't sure which one to post in.

Comment: The word for applications most commonly used in my experience is  "64-bit" or 32-bit" . That is normally what I see.

Comment: I've seen people use "bitness" to communicate this. As in, "the bitness of this application matters, and it can only run on 32-bit system"

Comment: "Width" is the word I'd use. (Though what do I know?)

Comment: I would prefer _bititude_; bitness with attitude. Or, if there are only two choices, 32 and 64, you can call one _little_ and the other _big_ and just use those as labels.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I suppose there's always "bitterness".

Comment: @JohnLawler, historically there were 16-bit (The IBM PC/AT and its clones, early Macs) and 8-bit (The original PC, Apple II, and numerous competitors) machines before there were 32-bit machines.

Comment: OP, just to be clear, are you asking about a *processor* (the CPU chip in the computer) being 32 or 64 bit, or are you asking about a *process* (a program or an execution thread that's part of a program) being 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Oh, I remember. Plus various other bases, not always powers of 2, like 7 and 12. But you mentioned only 32 and 64.

Answer (score 6):

The number of bits is the *word size* of the CPU, however I believe that you are referring to the [*architecture*](https://www.quora.com/What-is-CPU-architecture), which is a wider concept.

Comment: Specifically, the word size of the architecture.

Comment: True. I made the assumption that since the author of this question apparently didn't know they probably meant this, but you're right let's upgrade the answer

Comment: Ah! I think word size is exactly what I meant! I couldn't think of it. Thank you.

Comment: However, 64-bit versions of Windows can run both 32- and 64-bit applications; older, 32-bit versions of  Windows could run both 32- and 16-bit applications. The question as stated is looking for a word to describe the bitness of a process, not the platform.

Comment: Well, the word size of the code has to be implemented in the CPU, but it's still the word size